# How do I tell if a list contains NILs?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have the following list:

```
(X O X O X NIL X NIL O)
```

If I do `(find 'x (X O X O X NIL X NIL O))` it returns `X`, so I know the list contains `X`. But If I do `(find nil (X O X O X NIL X NIL O))` I get `NIL`, which is meaningless because I'd get `NIL` even if my list didn't contain `NIL`.

How can I tell if my list contains `NIL`s or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [position](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pos_p.htm#position)

```
(position NIL '(X O X O X NIL X NIL O))
--> 5
```

Answer (score 3):

It may not be as processor-efficient as the others, but I'd likely write it pretty much like I say it in English:

```
(some #'null '(X O X O X NIL X NIL O))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
(or 
  (map (lamdba (x)
    (eq? x nil))
       '(X O X O X NIL X NIL O)))
```

I don't have CL installed right now, but I think it would work.  (or works that way in CL, right?  or is there an `any` function?

EDIT:

Wait a second, nil counts as false, right?

```
(apply and '(X O X NIL))
;Or 
(all '(X O X NIL))
;Whichever works in CL.
```

Comment: eq? isn't a CL function. FYI. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to Haskell and Scheme.

Comment: `any` function is `some` which Ken suggested. And `apply and` won't work because `and` is a macro but `apply` can only be used with functions.

Comment: There's also no `all` function but instead `every` which needs a predicate. `notevery #'identity` would be the most similar working thing to your `all` example, but I think `some #'null` is much clearer than that.

Answer (score -1):

`NOT` is what you're looking for.

Here's an example:

```
 (reduce #'(lambda (a b) (or a b))
   (mapcar 'not '(1 2 3 4)))
```

Comment: What does your "Alternatively" comment mean?  That expression returns `(NIL NIL NIL NIL)`, and the `OR` does nothing (unless your list is empty) because it's only being passed one value.

Comment: There are actually three predicates in CL that are true only for `nil`. `not` is for those cases were the argument is to be interpreted as a boolean, `endp` is for arguments that are lists (and will signal an error if they aren't), and `null` is the general check for `nil` without specific semantics.

Comment: @Ken: Doh. That would be my bad.